# I've uploaded a file using multer, expressJs, NodeJs. Now I want to keep a View Button to view the last uploaded file in the front end, help ,me out

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, multer

I've no idea of how to view the file in front end.

I tried using,

```js
let fname = multer.diskStorage({
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(file.originalname);
  },
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("uploads");
  res.render(fname.toString("utf8"));
});
```

tried to convert the location to string and make it render, But got this error

> Error: Failed to lookup view "[object Object]" in views directory "D:\OODU\uploadImagesNodejs\views"

This is my **index.js** file

[image]

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path"); //Importing required libraries
const multer = require("multer");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "images"); //creating a storage destination for the uploaded files
  },

  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    console.log(file);
    cb(
      null,
      file.originalname.replace(/\.[^/.]/, "") +
        "_" +
        Date.now() +
        path.extname(file.originalname) //Adding timestamp to the file name to make it as an unique ID
    );
  },
});

const maxSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024; //Limiting the file size within 5MB to upload

let upload = multer({
  storage: storage, //File conditions for uploading (i.e: size, type)
  limits: {
    fileSize: maxSize,
  },
  fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
    let filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png/;
    let mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);
    let extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());

    if (mimetype && extname) {
      return cb(null, true);
    }

    cb(
      "Error: File upload only supports the following filetypes: " + filetypes
    );
  },
}).single("image");

app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

let fname = multer.diskStorage({
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(file.originalname);
  },
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("uploads");
  res.render(fname.toString("utf8"));
});

app.post("/uploads", (req, res, next) => {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      if (err instanceof multer.MulterError && err.code == "LIMIT_FILE_SIZE") {
        return res.send("file exceeds the allowed limit");
      }
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.send("uploaded successfully");
    }
  });
});

app.listen(3001);
console.log("3001 is the port");
```

This is my **upload.ejs** file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body style="justify-content: center; text-align: center">
    <form action="/uploads" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div><b style="color: blue"> File size should be within 2mb</b></div>
      <input type="file" name="image" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
      <a href="/images" class="btn"> view uploads </a>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can only call `res.render()` once per request. Why are you trying to pass the Multer diskstorage object? The argument you pass to `render()` should be the name of a template

Comment: @Phil I'm new to js development don't have much knowledge in the field. Sorry, to know that I have made a major mistake.